# non-negative curvature condition for polyhedral manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, alexandrov-geometry

A polyhedral manifold P, i.e, a topological manifold with a triangulation where each simplex is isometric to a simplex in Euclidean space (other constant curvature spaces are allowed), is said to have non-negative curvature (in the Alexandrov sense) iff the cone angle at every hyper-edge (simplices of codimension 2) is $\leq 2\pi.$ In fact, this condition is sometimes used as the definition of curvature bounded below by 0 on Euclidean polyhedral manifolds.

My question is: why does codimension 2 suffice? Assuming we do not know P is an Alexandrov space with curvature bounded below by 0, how would we prove that the curvature is $\geq 0$ in the Alexandrov sense, for instance, at a vertex? I can see this if $dim(P)=3,$ but this gets confusing pretty quickly in higher dimensions.

Any good references that actually prove these basic properties are also very welcome.